# How to call one method after another method in componentDidMount in Reacct

Tags: reactjs

Hi Have 2 methods I need to call one after another , I tried the solutions provided here but none working any simple example will help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which solutions, exactly?

Comment: `function1(); function2()` ? Do you mean you have aync functions you want to run in order?

Comment: Use `async/await` for `componentDidMount` would be fine